# How to compare (partial) subtrees of an XML document using XSLT, returning a boolean value based on the comparison as a single tag?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Assume the existence of a software system that enables the use of XSLTs to specify a certain predicate on an XML message. Specifically: transform an input document to an output document of the following form: `<predicate>true</predicate>` (or `<predicate>false</predicate>`).

For some simple cases (like *message contains `XPath`*) this is rather trivial, but I now need write an XSLT for something like the following:

```
<change>

  <!-- state before change -->
  <item>
    <name>
      <first>...</first>
      <last>...</last>
    </name>
    <something>
       ...
    </something>
  </item>

  <!-- state after change -->
  <item>
    <name>
      <first>...</first>
      <last>...</last>
    </name>
    <something>
       ...
    </something>
  </item>

</change>
```

And I would like to return `<predicate>true</predicate>` for a definition of a mutation if:

- The before or after state (or both) actually contain a subtree of `something` data (as this part is optional), so basically `change/item[1]/something | change/item[2]/something`, *and*
- The before and the after state with both having any `something` data removed are not identical to each other.

The second part could be something like the following pseudocode: `$before` variable is `change/item[1]/something` with any existing `something` subtree removed from it, `$after` variable is `change/item[2]/something` with any existing `something` subtree removed from it and then perhaps something like `not(deep-equal($before,$after))`...?

Anyone here have any idea how I could do this using XSLT 2.0, as I suspect this to be totally impossible in XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try along the lines of

```
<xsl:template match="change">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="item[1]/something | item[2]/something">
      <xsl:variable name="before" as="element(item)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item[1]" mode="rs"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="after" as="element(item)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item[2]" mode="rs"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <predicate><xsl:value-of select="not(deep-equal($before,$after))"/></predicate>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <predicate>false</predicate>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="rs">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="rs"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="something" mode="rs"/>
```

Untested but should give you an idea. It basically runs a transformation in `mode="rs"` (`remove-something`) on the two `item` elements to strip the `something` element, then it does the comparison you posted (`not(deep-equal($before,$after))`).